# Why do the clouds in this CSS animation move to a new line instead of leaving the page?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, web-frontend

I'm trying to have these clouds move across the web page and out of it, but the clouds keep moving to a new line. Here is the website: http://therealrohanm.me/Falcon-Hacks-Website/ (the clouds take a few seconds to show)

Here is the code: https://github.com/Meeshbhoombah/Falcon-Hacks-Website

How can I have them not move to a new line? Also, how can I the clouds down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a class to each of your clouds "cloud"

```
<img class="cloud-1" src="images/Cloud.png">
```

should become

```
<img class="cloud cloud-1" src="images/Cloud.png">
```

Then add some CSS:

```
#animated-cloud-background .cloud {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked, but how would I go about delaying some clouds? I tried using the animation-delay property but that didn't do it.

Comment: try -webkit-transition-delay: __s; & transition-delay: __s;

Comment: Have you tried making a class for every cloud which the only property it contains is the -WebKit-transition-delay: _s;(as @RohanMishra said) with different delays?